# How do I restrict a type of weapon?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

My militia took my battle axes and won't give 'em back to my woodcutters. I'd rather not resort to killing my militia. How do I make them give my workers their tools back?

Comment: I love reading the questions to this game :)

Comment: I almost don't want to play it because then the questions will make sense to me. :-p

Comment: @NPC @Mechko glad you find my dwarfs' idiosyncrasies amusing. I HATE THEM ALL!!!11one!!

Comment: The antics are amusing.  Like when your two skilled militia members get beat up by a single goblin thief in a 3 by 3 room, then let him escape...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disband the squad.  This should cause the militia to drop their weapons.  Then re-create the squad with a uniform that requires a specific weapon (not a battle axe).

If this doesn't work you can dump, then unforbid the soldier's battle axes.  Some little hauler will come and wrench the axe from your soldier's hands.